Alternative Stack Exchange sites for "not really about the Chinese language" questions
I thought I'd make a list of Stack Exchange sites which have questions related to the Chinese language.
Language-related...
--> Language Learning (+tag)

Language Learning Stack Exchange is for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of language acquisition.
What topics can I ask about here?, Language Learning


Example: Explaining the difference between 'very' and 'too' to native Chinese speakers

Example: How useful is it to study Chinese using Duolingo's English for Chinese speakers course?

Example: Is it easy for native Japanese speakers to remember simplified Chinese characters?


--> Linguistics (+tag; also languages-of-China)

The Linguistics Stack Exchange Site is a Q&A for linguists, language enthusiasts and people who have some interest in how languages work. What is Linguistics? It is the scientific study of languages.
What topics can I ask about here?, Linguistics


Example: If two syllables in Mandarin have the same vowels but different tones, can the syllables be said to rhyme?

Example: Why are Chinese punctuation marks 。and 、so similar to its western style equivalents?

Example: Does Chinese have proper nouns and are they distinguished morphosyntactically or only lexically and or semantically?


--> Japanese (+tag; also kanji)

Japanese Language Stack Exchange is for students, teachers, and linguists who want to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language.
What topics can I ask about here?, Japanese


Example: Why is 犬 used to refer to “dog” in Japanese?
Example: Can a Japanese person understand something written in traditional Chinese
Example: Can I use my Chinese name as my Japanese name?

--> Korean (+tag)

What topics can I ask about here?  Word choice and usage, grammar, and pronunciation, including dialect differences, Korean linguistics, orthography (spelling, punctuation) or etymology, ...
What topics can I ask about here?, Korean


Example: Where did Korean get its reading of 秒?
Example: Do Korean share more vocabulary with Chinese or Japanese?

--> English Language & Usage (+tag)

The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.
What topics can I ask about here?, English Language & Usage


Example: What is an English equivalent of the Chinese noun 心眼?

Example: English equivalent of two popular Chinese slang terms: 学霸 (academic overlord) and 学婊 (academic bitch)


Software/web-related...
--> Super User (+tag)

Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users.
What topics can I ask about here?, Super User


Example: How to type pinyin text with tone marks in Windows?

Example: Windows 7 Home Premium - Unable to View Chinese Characters Properly


--> Software Recommendations

This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”.
What topics can I ask about here?, Software Recommendations


Example: Aligning Chinese and English translations

Example: Plain text editor that supports vertical text (for Chinese, Japanese, etc)

Example: Chinese Sentiment Analysis Tools


--> Graphic Design (+fonts)

Graphic Design SE is for questions targeted toward design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
What topics can I ask about here?, Graphic Design


Example: Where to find a handwritten font with English and Chinese?
Example: Does this Chinese font fit in with our brand?
Example: Help Identify the Japanese and Chinese Fonts as Pictured

--> Web Applications

Web Applications Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
What topics can I ask about here?, Web Applications


Example: How to make Simplified Chinese preferences on Wikipedia stick?

Example: How to post via email on Sina Weibo


--> Unix and Linux

Unix and Linux Stack Exchange is for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.
What topics can I ask about here?, Unix and Linux


Example: How to make Chinese characters display properly on Chromium
Example: Extract only chinese characters

--> AskUbuntu

It's a questions and answers site for Ubuntu-related questions. It's also a place to share knowledge about Ubuntu.
What topics can I ask about here?, AskUbuntu


Example: How do I get Chinese input to work?

Example: Are there plans for handwriting recognition?


--> Ask Different (aka Apple.SE)

Ask Different is for users of Apple products.
What topics can I ask about here?, Ask Different


Example: How to filter for Chinese fonts in Font Book on Sierra?

Example: Specifying the keyboard layout for Chinese input

Example: How can I type Chinese on MacBook Pro?


--> Android Enthusiasts (+tag)

Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is for users of the Android operating system.
What topics can I ask about here?, Android Enthusiasts


Example: Is there an official Chinese handwriting input method for Android?

--> TeX (+tag)

This site is for enthusiastic users of TeX and related systems: people who love to create well-structured and beautifully typeset documents.
What topics can I ask about here?, TeX


Example: How do I extract the definition(s) of a Chinese word from the CC-EDICT dictionary?

Example: Typesetting bopomofo (zhuyinfuhao) on right side of Chinese characters with ruby


Food...
--> Seasoned Advice (+food-identification; chinese-cuisine)

This site is for professional and amateur cooks and chefs, and anyone else who works in the kitchen or is interested in preparing and serving delicious meals.
What topics can I ask about here?, Seasoned Advice


Example: What's 香茜 or 芫荽 in English?
Example: What is this seafood that I bought in a Chinese market?
Example: What is the Chinese celery and cabbage appetizer called and how is it made?


Sites that have a [China] tag...

Travel (tag; 718 Q's) There's also a Chinese-Citizens tag
History (tag; 281 Q's) There's also the Ancient-China and Medieval-China tags
Politics (tag; 201 Q's)
Skeptics (tag; 74 Q's)
Expatriates (tag; 54 Q's)
Space Exploration (tag; 42 Q's)
Personal Finance and Money (tag; 40 Q's)
Server Fault (tag; 35 Q's)
Mythology and Folklore (tag; 27 Q's)  [Note: the tag here is "Chinese", but it refers to "Chinese mythology" and not the "Chinese language".]
Philosophy (tag; 26 Q's)  [Note: the tag here is "Chinese-philosophy".]
Economics (tag; 26 Q's)
Geographic Information Systems (tag; 25 Q's)
Buddhism (tag; 22 Q's)  [Note: the tag here is "Chinese-Buddhism".]  There's also a Chinese-canon tag
Academia (tag; 14 Q's)
Law (tag; 14 Q's)
Open Data (tag; 12 Q's)
Literature (tag; 12 Q's)  [Note: the tag here is "Chinese-literature".]
Ask Patents (tag; 11 Q's)
StackOverflow Meta (tag; 11 Q's)
Bitcoin (tag; 9 Q's)
The Workplace (tag; 9 Q's)
Aviation (tag; 8 Q's)
Christianity (tag; 6 Q's)
Interpersonal Skills (tag; 6 Q's)
Quantitative Finance (tag; 5 Q's)
Genealogy and Family History (tag; 4 Q's)
Amateur Radio (tag; 1 Q')

Stackoverflow has the Chinese-Locale and Great-Firewall-Of-China tags.  History of Science and Mathematics has Ancient-China.

But there’re also many other questions that have no better place to go apart from Chinese SE.
Since there’s no Vietnamese Language Stack Exchange,  there’s no other place to direct questions pertaining to Sino-Vietnamese vocabulary and Chữ Nôm script. 
It’s really in a league of its own, like the Kanji and Hanja of the Japanese and Korean SEs.
You probably couldn’t ask about influences of the Chinese language on Mongolian/Tibetan/Manchu on any other SE, since the separate languages don’t have SEs.
I would say it isn’t too practical to ask them on Linguistics, since it’s very Chinese-oriented and most people who do ask these questions already have an understanding of how the Chinese language works, but it also doesn’t warrant for the creation of new language SEs, since most of these aspects are typically the more obscure parts of the languages’ development.

Actually, I brought up something similar recently on Area 51: Would a general Languages.SE supersite (synchronized with the current language sites) be feasible?.  As things stand, not every question has a home on Stack Exchange.

“Having English as the main language of instruction” really shouldn’t be too much of a concern, especially on such sites which are meant to break down language barriers in the first place
